# How to search and give a list of suggestions by using a textBox?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm devloping a mail system and I want to search emails through a textbox and give some suggestions when the user enters the first letters.

How can I achieve this, can you help me?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few ways to achieve this. [Here is](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/act_AutoComplete_Simple.ashx) a example of a simple auto-complete textbox in asp, but a suggest you to use jquery and its [`autocomplete()`](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/) function which is simpler:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>jQuery UI Autocomplete - Default functionality</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script>
  $(function() {
    var availableTags = [
      "ActionScript",
      "AppleScript",
      "Asp",
      "BASIC",
      "C",
      "C++",
      "Clojure",
      "COBOL",
      "ColdFusion",
      "Erlang",
      "Fortran",
      "Groovy",
      "Haskell",
      "Java",
      "JavaScript",
      "Lisp",
      "Perl",
      "PHP",
      "Python",
      "Ruby",
      "Scala",
      "Scheme"
    ];

    $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
      source: availableTags
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="ui-widget">
  <label for="tags">Tags: </label>
  <input id="tags" />
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use TextBox.AutoCompleteMode property.

```
var source = new AutoCompleteStringCollection();
source.AddRange(new string[]
                {
                    "January",
                    "February",
                    "March",
                    "April",
                    "May",
                    "June",
                    "July",
                    "August",
                    "September",
                    "October",
                    "November",
                    "December"
                });

//Add datasource to textbox
textbox.AutoCompleteCustomSource = source;
textbox.AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend;
textbox.AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.CustomSource;
```